# Why I can't add some assemblies to my referenced assemblies

Tags: c#, assemblies

With the code:

```
 CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
 parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
 parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
```

So far, it is good and it works and I can run the code that I give to it, but if I add these assemblies:

```
    //parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Text.dll");
    //parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Linq.dll");
```

at run-time it gives me an error saying:

> Metadata file "System.Text" couldn't be found.

So what am I doing wrong in here?

Answer (score 6):

There are no `System.Text` and `System.Linq` *assemblies*. There are *namespaces* called that, but it's a different thing entirely.

LINQ is implemented in `System.Core.dll`; you can see this e.g. in the documentation for [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Linq.Enumerable.aspx):

> Namespace: `System.Linq`
>
> Assembly: `System.Core` (in `System.Core.dll`)

To find out which assemblies you need to reference, just browse the documentation for the types you are interested in and see what assembly implements them. Since the .NET library developers value consistency you will find that namespaces are implemented in the same assembly in their entirety (at least *I* do not know of any exceptions).

Comment: if I want the user to be able to use Linq or some System.IO methods, etc...then what other Assemblies I should load?

Comment: @BDotA: Finished updating the answer, check it out.

Comment: Thanks, got it but even with parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");  it gives me the same error as before. :(